# Vuetify Custom Column Filtering of Dates

Tags: filtering, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have columns in my table that are dates.  They're presented to the user in `MMM YYYY` (e.g. `JAN 2020`) format.  I want the user to be able to filter based on those months and years - if they type "Jan" they should get all the January rows, etc.  Same for years.

According to the Vuetify [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#custom-filtering) for Data Tables:

> You can override the default filtering used with `search` prop by supplying a function to the `custom-filter` prop. **If you need to customize the filtering of a specific column, you can supply a function to the `filter` property on header items**. The signature is `(value: any, search: string | null, item: any) => boolean`. This function will always be run even if `search` prop has not been provided. Thus you need to make sure to exit early with a value of `true` if filter should not be applied.

I have a couple of headers that call supply the filterDate function as required:

```js
{
    text: "Contract Delivery",
    value: "contractDate",
    align: "center",
    sortable: true,
    filter: this.filterDate
},
{
    text: "Nominal Delivery",
    value: "targetDeliveryDate",
    align: "center",
    sortable: true,
    filter: this.filterDate
},
```

... and the function itself:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-us", {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "short"
});

export default {
   // ... other stuff redacted
   methods: {
      filterDate(dateString, search) {
         // dateString is a string from the database, not a handy month and year

         if (dateString == null || search == null || search == "") return true;

         let month = "";
         let year = "";

         formatter
            .formatToParts(new Date(dateString)) // make it a date and get the bits
            .map(({ type, value }) => {
                switch (type) {
                   case "month":
                     this.month = value.ToLowerCase();
                     break;
                   case "year":
                     this.year = value;
                     break;
            });

          return month.indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || year.indexOf(search) !== -1
        });

      }    
   }
}
```

... but this obviously doesn't work - and I can't make it work even if I make the entire `formatDate` just `return true`.  I'm at a loss.